# How can I set rails routes to redirect some urls to another controller with parameter and default action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I want to mix the two line below with one. 
I guess it is possible but I don't know.
any ideas you have?

```
match '/alias4' => redirect("/original/4") # redirect to original#show => 4                                                                                                                                              
match '/alias4(/:action)' => redirect("/original/4/%{action}") # redirect to some actions (not restful)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match '/alias4(/:action)' => redirect("/original/4/%{action}"), :defaults => { :action => "show" }
```

should work.

*Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults .*

Comment: It works great. I read that guide but I guess that is just for format.  Thank you very much.!!

Comment: You're welcome. The normal thing is to give this answer a tick if it helped you solve your question :). All the best.